# Tension in a string, at an angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, free-body-diagram, string, statics

[image]

This was a question on a mechanics exam. Part i wants me to assume that the tension in  both parts of the string is the same. Even though I got the correct answer( 18.9N) by assuming so, I don't understand how this assumption makes sense. Consider the bit of string under the ring. The net force on it must be zero ( light string ) so that implies the net vertical component is zero. This is not possible if I assume the tensions to be the same, or at least that's how I see it ( see image)

Basically in my mind: If the tensions are equal, the net force on the bit in contact with the ring can not be zero since the angles are different. But since the string is light, this does not add up. ( Or the system is at rest. Net force on that bit of rope must be zero, regardless of light/ not light)

But the question assumes the opposite. I would like to know what part of my argument here is flawed.

Comment: *What am I missing ?* Nothing. Now draw a free body/force diagram to prove that...

Comment: @Gert, please see the edited question.

Comment: Even using using a free body diagram I am able to get only two 
 equations(equilibrium in the horizontal and verical directions)for a question with 3 variables.Something is issing ... unless the answer is in terms of X. I think.

Comment: Tension in a massless string has to be same so T1=T2

Comment: @Sal_99 What did the book say the tension is?

Comment: @Sal_99 is the tension having a numerical value

Comment: If the answer is $18.9\ \rm N$ then they are assuming the ring is supported by the net vertical force supplied by both of the strings. This is only possible then for a specific value of $X$

Comment: @Sal_99 Then for the sum of the vertical forces to be zero, we have 8=0.766RB-0.342RA. Setting RA=RB (tension same throughout) gives us RA=RB=18.9. Is that what was done? And then you can calculate the force X summing the horizontal forces.

Comment: Regardless of whether this is on-topic or not (I'm inclined to think it is), the homework-and-exercises tag is appropriate, since the question is about a physics exercise.

Comment: I'm new to this. Do I have to wait for someone to review and reopen the question, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First answering to your doubt of tension being same in both parts of string.
Young's modulus of a material is constant irrespective of shape length etc. (at least from the point of view of solving high school questions ) , you can study about it a bit on the internet if you don't know it already. $$Y={{F\over A}\over {\Delta L\over L}} $$where $Y$ is the Young's modulus of elasticity of your string.From here $$F={YA\over L}(\Delta L)$$As you can see from this equation,  the force or the tension for a realistic string depends on its extension and the constants beside it.Moreover the Force equation depends inversely on the actual length of string too (see L in the denominator ), so unless you cut the string where the ring is and then attach both parts above and below the ring , the force equations are not going to change and the string as a continuous entity will have same tension everywhere , because $\Delta L$ here accounts for whole string.

The purpose of invoking elasticity in the picture is to explain the tension aspect in near ideal conditions , there is nothing like a mass less string but the above explanation is a close analysis.

Coming to the actual question (tension is now same  throughout the string). 
**HORIZONTAL EQUILIBRIUM** $$T(cos50+cos20)=X$$ **VERTICAL EQUILIBRIUM** $$T(sin50)=T(sin20)+(0.8)g$$

Upon solving these two , $T=18.66 N$ and $X=29.29 N$ approx.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The issue with the tension idea is that since the string is light , net force on any bit must be zero ( net F= ma) . Let's suppose the tension is the same in this set up. Let's consider the bit of string under the ring. If both tensions pulling on this bit are the same then , due to different angles, the net **vertical** component on this bit isn't zero , and so net force isn't zero. I completely agree with your discussion on elastic properties but it is this bit I can not get across. True, this analysis is based on a massless string - a theoretical idea- but the question gives me permission

Comment: @Sal_99 You missed a force , the weight of ring , the upward pulling tension balances weight of ring + downward pulling tension

Comment: @Sal_99 You do want a non-zero net force on the part of the ring where the string threads through. If this was not the case then the weight of the ring and $X$ would not be able to be canceled out.

Comment: @Sal_99 I'm trying to understand your confusion as well. Could it have something to do with external vs internal forces. Clearly the sum of the external forces (the fixed points A and B and whatever is applying the force X) has to be zero for this system (strings plus ring) to be in equilibrium. But tension is an internal force in the system, like the tension in a spring. If you cut section RA and tied the ends to a spring scale you would get the same scale reading if you cut section RB and put the scale there.

Comment: @BobD Based on the comment "*How is the weight of the ring acting on the bit of string?*", it seems like the OP is under the impression that if we just focus (zoom in maybe?) on the part of the ring where the string is threaded through then you no longer have to consider the weight of the ring. This, of course, is not the case.

Comment: @Sal_99 Concerning you statement "I am interested only as to what is happening to that bit of string in contact with the ring. My confusion is that setting the tension the same across results in a non zero net force on that bit", how can you ignore the X force acting to the right on the ring and the weight of the ring acting down that, together with the tension forces at each end of the bit of string, that result in a net force of zero?

Comment: @Sal_99 Just as Aditya Prakash just put up in his answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91628/discussion-between-aditya-prakash-and-sal-99).

Comment: This answer answers the question primarily due to the second diagram in the answer. The contact force on the string makes the connection and shows where my argument was flawed.

Comment: Though I still wonder if this is the only explanation.

Answer (score 0):

First, since the ring doesn't involve any corners, sharp angles, etc. we can safely assume the tension is uniform throughout the massless string that is threaded through the ring.

Assuming that the vertical components of tension is equal to the vertical force the ring experiences due to each string, then $X$ must take a specific value consistent with Newton's laws in the horizontal direction. There is no issue in having a constant tension throughout the string.

Indeed, if you do the work for general angles (you can do the work yourself) you will find
$$X=\left(\frac{\cos\theta_A+\cos\theta_B}{\sin\theta_A-\sin\theta_B}\right)mg$$
If we were to change the applied force $X$, then this would just result in different angles. Although notice that, for angles less between $0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$, we cannot have $\sin\theta_A<\sin\theta_B$ or else $X<0$. In other words, as we pull harder and harder ($X$ gets larger and larger) the angles will both approach $45^\circ$.

Comment: About point 1, what I don't I get is why. Yes a massless string means net force on any bit must be 0. If we set tension equal in both bits of strings above and below the ring, the net force on the bit under the ring isn't 0 since the angles are different. There are cases where tension in a massless string isn't the same where angles change, as my teacher points out.

Comment: @Sal_99 What was the book answer for the tension?

Comment: About point 2, the question says the ring is smooth

Comment: @Sal_99 What was the book answer for the tension in the string?

Comment: @Aaron Stevens , the ring is  <i>smooth</i> , so no friction to support the ring vertically

Comment: The answer in the book is 18.9

Comment: @Sal_99 Greatly edited my answer

Comment: I agree with everything after the first paragraph. It is this assumption that I don't get. If the tensions are equal, the net force on the bit in contact with the ring can not be zero since the angles are different. But since the string is light, this does not add up. I don't get why the fact there are no sharp edges,etc makes sense of this.

Comment: @Sal_99 the net force of just the strings cannot ever be $0$. The ring has weight and I am assuming $X$ is non-zero. The string through the ring providing a non-zero net force is not an issue, it is what is happening.

Comment: Yes exactly. If you draw a free body diagram for **just the bit of string in contact with the ring**,  you would say the net force on it is not zero, yes?

Comment: @Sal_99 Yes, that is correct. The net forces due to the string from A to B will have components upward and to the left, which are then canceled out by the weight of the ring and X when you consider the system as a whole.

Comment: Yes. You've understood my confusion now. We accept that the net force on the bit of string ALONE isn't zero. Now this bit of string has no mass ( light) so it not possible for it to have a net force on it. And that is my concern

Comment: Let me put it like this , the bit of string is experiencing a net upward force due to tension etc. and since that bit is holding the ring , the ring , that extra net force is used up in supporting the weight of ring , is it okay?